# In what format does Joomla! stores the password

Tags: joomla-3.x, authentication, account-password

I am looking at the Joomla! .htaccess file. In which encoding does Joomla! stores the password. Can it be decoded as well?

Comment: is it base64 encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.htaccess file has nothing to do with Joomla! passwords.

**Joomla < 3.2**

Passwords are [MD5](http://php.net/md5) hashed and salted. Salt is 32 characters long random string. They are stored in database like `{hash}:{salt}`.

**Joomla >= 3.2**

Like @Lodder said, starting from 3.2, passwords are hashed using Bcrypt.

These passwords can't be decrypted.

If you want to recover your lost admin password, follow Joomla! docs about [How do you recover or reset your admin password?](https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F).

Answer (score 4):

You've specifically tagged your question with Joomla 3.x, so assuming you're using Joomla 3.2 or later, passwords are hashed using the [Bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) which is considered one the best method available today.

MD5 hash and salt were used in older versions of Joomla

The passwords are stored in the `#__users` table and no, they can not be decoded, but can be reset.